# Parallel read the contents of a zipped file without extraction

Tags: zip, gnu-parallel, concurrency

I have the following zip archive structure:

```
$ unzip -l Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc.zip 
Archive:  Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/
        0  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Icons/
        0  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/
     1197  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Icons/fastqc_icon.png
     1450  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Icons/warning.png
     1561  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Icons/error.png
     1715  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Icons/tick.png
      782  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/summary.txt
     9095  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/per_base_quality.png
    14381  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/per_tile_quality.png
    23205  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/per_sequence_quality.png
    30978  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/per_base_sequence_content.png
    31152  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/per_sequence_gc_content.png
     7861  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/per_base_n_content.png
    18356  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/sequence_length_distribution.png
    23040  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/duplication_levels.png
     9096  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/adapter_content.png
    58683  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/Images/kmer_profiles.png
   355919  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/fastqc_report.html
   301092  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/fastqc_data.txt
    10117  10-10-14 14:44   Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc/fastqc.fo
 --------                   -------
   899680                   21 files
```

How is it possible to use `fastqc_data.txt` with `crimson` in parallel, because at the moment I get the following error:

```
find `pwd`/*_fastqc.zip -type f | parallel -j 3 unzip -c {} {}/fastqc_data.txt | crimson fastqc {} | less

Usage: crimson fastqc [OPTIONS] INPUT [OUTPUT]

Error: Invalid value for "input": Path "{}" does not exist.
```

Comment: In most shells you need to quote the `{}`, so use e.g. `\{\}`.

Comment: @dirkt Among the common and even less common shells, you only need to quote `{}` in fish. This is not the problem.

Comment: I tried all combination of `\{\}`, but still I have the same problem. What else did I miss?

Comment: WRong version of Parallel? E.g. not GNU? Try parallel --version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pipeline made of four commands:

- `find`, which lists zip files.
- `parallel`, which invokes `unzip` to extract one file in each zip file. Given that `{}` is replaced by the path to the zip file, you attempt to extract files like `home/user977828/stuff/Undetermined_S0_L004_R1_001_fastqc.zip/fastqc_data.txt` from the archive (if the current directory is `/home/user977828/stuff`).
- `crimson`, which receives a jumble of the extracted files on standard input, and is invoked with the arguments `fastqc` and `{}`,
- `less`.

`parallel` only substitutes `{}` in its arguments. It can't do anything about the other parts of your pipeline. If you want to invoke `crimson` on each `fastqc_data.txt`file separately, you need to pass a pipeline from `unzip` to `crimson` as an argument to `parallel`.

```
find *_fastqc.zip -type f | sed 's/\.zip$//' |
parallel -j 3 'unzip -c {}.zip {}/fastqc_data.txt | crimson fastqc /dev/stdin' |
less
```

Comment: I changed your command to write to an output file `find `pwd`/test/*_fastqc.zip -type f | sed 's/\.zip$//' | parallel -j 2 'unzip -c {}.zip {}/fastqc_data.txt | crimson fastqc /dev/stdin > {}.json'` but now I got 
``caution: filename not matched:  /home/lorencm/test/Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001_fastqc/fastqc_data.txt``

Comment: find `pwd`/test/*_fastqc.zip  does not work, but find *_fastqc.zip works. Any idea why?

Comment: @user977828 Whatever `parallel` receives as input is used twice: once to build the name of the zip file (`{}.zip`) and once as the name of the directory inside the zip. If you want them to be different, you have to extract the relevant part, e.g. `find … | parallel 'dir={}; dir=${dir%.zip}; dir=${dir##*/}; unzip -c {} "$dir/fastqc_data.txt" | …'`

Comment: @user977828 Use `parallel 'set -x; …` to print a trace of what the shell launched by parallel is executing.